# What is the ancient Chinese one-character name for woman like '子’ means man?

Tags: usage, classical-chinese, old-chinese, gender

青青子衿，悠悠我心。但为君故，沉吟至今

Here:

子，对对方的尊称

子 implicitly implies the poem is addressing a man. The poem talks about how a lady misses a man. I just wonder if there is a corresponding word for Chinese. (i.e. what would you replace 子 by, if it were talking about a woman?

Comment: Does a native speaker's opinion make sense? The first sentense doesn't mention the lover to be missed is a male person; 子 at here means "you". The reason why it's different than appearances in other references is it's making a "dual" with 我. This is common in 诗经, where this poem comes from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The equivalent of `子` for women is also `子`.**

> 【清·張自烈·正字通】子部：女子亦稱子

Examples from Old Chinese texts:

> 【孟子·告子下】逾東家牆而摟其處子，則得妻，不摟，則不得妻，則將摟之乎？

- The Works of Mencius: "*Breaking into your landlord's house and harass the virgin girl gets you a wife; refrain from harassing and you don't get a wife. Does that mean you would do it?*"

> 【詩經·國風·周南·桃夭】桃之夭夭，灼灼其華；之子于歸，宜其室家!

- The Classic of Poetry: "*Forests are green and flowers are red; a girl is marrying, and she'll make her new family happy.*"

---

In ancient Chinese, `女` either meant "unmarried woman" or "you". The character for the latter usage became `汝`, but is still printed as `女` in many modern publications of ancient works.

Comment: In addition, "女子" means women and children in Classical Chinese.

Comment: I also want to point that the difference between 汝(less formal) and 子(more formal) is formality, not gender

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is 女.

There are books such as 女訓 (Advice for Women) and 烈女傳 (Biographies of Notable Women).

Also, 子 in 青青子衿 explicity referring to the `lady's lover` (where the whole sentence means her lover's green collar) , instead of referring to a `man`.

Comment: 子 also means son, does that implies the lady's lover is a male?

Comment: Depends on it's usage.  For example, 女子 means girl but 兒子 means son

Comment: @user3919509 yes, it implicitly means male. 子 here implicitly means 'you' (male). I am not so sure if a substitution with ' 女' works here.

Answer (score 1):

**Re:...if it is talking about a woman?**

> Seems like this would be 女.

Comment: @user3919509 yes, it implicitly means male. 子 here implicitly means 'you' (male). I am not so sure if a substitution with ' 女' works here.

Comment: @Lost1 - Sorry I don't follow your comment. It seems to be on the wrong post. But, unless I misunderstand your request, you are asking for the single character for a woman (not a male). If you need something different, please modify the original question for clarity.